# Protect data from firebug specific ability in changin values

Tags: security, session

My problem is about how can we protect data like user_id or ordered_post_id?
Imagine we have a url with some arguments like user_id and etc.
we can generate url with Dom via reading html elements( < tag id="user_id" > User ID Here < /tag >), but here is one problem! Bad hackers can change "User ID Here" with firebug.

One solution is storing data with sessions, but there is no accessibility to our data when one user click on a specific button for generating our URL which is responsible for handling some Logic tasks.

how can i protect data and having on demand accessibility on data?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not trust anything sent to you by the client.

You should store the user id in your server session, the client can only tell you that his session is #client_session (and don't make them correlatives).

Comment: ...well, except that nearly every major website does this. :) You can trust data sent to you by the client so long as it is protected by the server and can be validated again by the server when it is re-submitted (ex: signed by the server).

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTTPS` connection instead of plain `HTTP`. The URL will be encrypted so a hacker will not have access to your "special" URL to extract the data

Comment: Instead of HTTPS we can use HMAC Verification, i'm looking for better simple way :d :-/

Whats the solution in shopping website?

Comment: A shopping website would use SSL by default.Have you ever send your credit card info to shop in an *non* HTTPS connection?I really hope not